# Finding the shortest path between two points in a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose we have a metric space $M = (V,d)$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. I want to find the function $\gamma(t)$ so that $\gamma(0) = a$, $\gamma(1) = b$ and
$$ d(a,b) = d(a,\gamma(t)) + d(\gamma(t),b), t \in [0, 1] $$
So essentially I want to find the shortest curve between two points in a generic metric space. I start from $a$ and travel to $b$ on the shortest curve in $1$ time unit. What's my position at $t$ moment? We know that in Euclidean spaces $\gamma(t)$ is the linear interpolation. How can I find the interpolation on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with a generic distance function which gives the shortest path?

Comment: This looks like a job for... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations !

Comment: What does "on $\mathbb R^n$" mean here?

Comment: A vector space which has vectors with $n$ dimension.

Answer (score 1):

There need not be a shortest curve with the desired property. In $\Bbb R^2\setminus [0,\infty)\times \{0\}$ with inherited metric,

- the distance between $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ is $2$,
- the infimum over all curve lengths between the two points is
  $2\sqrt2$,
- but every curve is longer.